# Can we retrieve pinterest user email address?

Tags: pinterest

I am using Pinterest in my web application and am trying to retrieve the authenticated user's email id so that I can send application related updates/subscriptions to his/her id. I would like to know if there is any way out to get the authenticated user's email address .Have tried to get a valid API documentation for web applications but couldn't find one. Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

No, You cant get email address of Authenticated user via API. Pintrest do not provide that detail through API.

Comment: And that is good I might add. This way some random dude with API access can't spam the users with unwanted emails. Might even be illegal to provide the email adresses.